# android - dynamically changing background

Tags: android, performance, hashmap, drawable

I have three backgrounds, say for the activity.  The displayed background will depend on the code.  Aside from using switch/if, is there another way I can pull this off.

I'm thinking of having a static `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`.  The second parameter is for the drawable, so I'll just use something like map.get(key) to get the drawable.

My only concern for this is performance, will storing the drawable in a key-palue pair HashMap and retrieving the value via `map.get(key)` affects the performance? Is it an expensive thing to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using `HashMap`, you can use [`SparseIntArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html), which is more efficient. Other than that, I don't think it is expensive to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine. I doubt that any performance hit you do take (if any) will be noticeable to the human eye